# AngularJS express coffee-assets controller not found

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, angularjs

In my AngularJS node.js [app](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee) based on [angular-express-blog](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-blog) and [express-coffee](https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee) I have an issue with defenition `angular.module` before controllers [pic](http://clip2net.com/s/2bkYH):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: IndexCtrl is not defined
```

The order of including modules the same as in angular-seed:

```
// JS
!= js('lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')
!= js('lib/bootstrap.min.js')
!= js('lib/angular.min.js')

!= js('app')
!= js('controllers')
!= js('directives')
!= js('filters')
!= js('services')
```

After change order to this:

```
!= js('controllers')
!= js('app')
!= js('directives')
!= js('filters')
!= js('services')
```

Error the same. It works only when I replace controllers to app.coffee before `angular.module("myApp"...` defenition. I restarted server of course.

Update: [app file](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee/blob/master/assets/js/app.coffee), [controller file](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee/blob/master/assets/js/controllers.coffee) and [layout](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee/blob/master/views/layout.jade)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Coffeescript, compiled things are wrapped in a closure:

```
//controllers.js:
(function() { function MyController($scope) {} })();
```

Now index.html can't find the MyController variable because it's in a closure!

Use the `module.controller` syntax instead.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller 'MyController', ($scope) ->
```

This will cause your controller to be visible everywhere.

Comment: This line `angular.module('myApp').controller 'MyController', ($scope) ->` I should add for all controllers? I had added it but the same error. With any order app and controllers. All files started with `(function() {  "use strict";` anyway.

Comment: If controller goes before module Error is `no module: myApp`

Comment: I added link to files in update. Error is the same. You could colne it and check, I would be pleased to any help, because I can't fix this issue about a week.

Comment: Do 'IndexCtrl' in quotes in your `$routeProvider.when`s.  Your controllers are no longer variables, so you reference them by name in quotes.